# Centering text/heading over columns

Tags: tables

I would like to center the headings Normal, Student-t and GED over the two columns such that they sit directly centered above the bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  SS
  l
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  SS
}

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
 &  & {Normal}  &  &  & {Student-t} &  &  & {GED} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}  \cmidrule(lr){9-10} % center non-numerical info (A, B, ...) by placing them in braces
 & {s}  & {KLIC} & {CSL} &   & {KLIC} & {CSL} &  & {KLIC} & {CSL} \\
\midrule  % leave gap between the two rules
GARCH
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.001 & & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.826 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.826 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
GJR
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.008 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
MS
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.998 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.812 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.811 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the edit of your comment so I replaced my comment with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` to center over two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  SS
  l
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  SS
}

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
 && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Normal}  && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Student-t}  && \multicolumn{2}{c}{GED} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}  \cmidrule(lr){9-10} % center non-numerical info (A, B, ...) by placing them in braces
 & {s}  & {KLIC} & {CSL} &   & {KLIC} & {CSL} &  & {KLIC} & {CSL} \\
\midrule  % leave gap between the two rules
GARCH
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.001 & & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.826 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.826 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
GJR
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.008 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
MS
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.998 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.812 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.811 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]